# how to get today's date in sql with specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have this format in my table:

```
2015-03-19 10:33:16.983
```

but I would like to convert it into this format:

```
 3/18/2015 12:00:00 AM.
```

How can I get that format?

```
select myDate from myTable
```

Comment: You really should leave the formatting to the front end.

Comment: As different versions of SQL Server support different date functions you should tag your question with the specific version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Convert

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), myDate, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), myDate, 108) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),myDate),2)
FROM myTable
```

This would give you the exact output you requested

mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM

(Or PM depending on time)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [Convert()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function.

Something like

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),3) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(getdate() AS TIME),100)
```

You can change 3 as per your local. 3 here will mean it in DD/MM/YYYY format i.e, British and French local.

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste this and alter as you need:

```
DECLARE @StartTimestamp  datetime
SET @StartTimestamp     = CAST((CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETUTCDATE()), 106)) AS datetime)

SELECT CONVERT(varchar, @StartTimestamp, 103) + CONVERT(varchar, @StartTimestamp, 108)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use two `convert`s with a `cast` and a `right` function:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 101) + 
' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), getdate(), 108) + 
' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),getdate()),2)
```

**OUTPUT:** `03/19/2015 18:44:19 PM`